# Testing WebFlux results in sequential execution of a Flux component

Tags: spring, testing, spring-webflux

I created a Flux which 3 Monos are subscribed to. The Flux does this by the .share() method. The Flux runs ONCE and saves an entry to the database. During this process, the Monos are able to use the result of the Flux for their own purposes. Everything works fine when running the application and testing it in swagger (This means I see the one entry in the database). However, when using WebTestClient to integration test the endpoint, I notice the amount of database entries is proportional to the Monos that subscribe to it. This makes me think the Flux is running sequentially for each mono and not running once and sharing its results. I created a small example of what is happening. The code is not accurately recreated but I cant share the actual code as it is copyrighted.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Sl4j
@RestController
@PostMappping("/icecreamorder")
public ResponseEntity<Mono<String>> postIceCreamOrder(@RequestBody Order order) {
    var result = iceCreamService.processOrder(order)
    return ResponseEntity.ok(result)
}

// MAIN SERVICE 
public class iceCreamService {
    /*
    various reposiory implementations
    */
    @Transactional
    public Mono<String> processOrder(Order order) {
        Flux<OrderTuple> tupleToShare = saveOrder(order)
        .flatMap(orderId -> saveMasterOrder(order))
        .map(parentOrder -> new MasterOrderTuple(orderId, parentOrder.getT1, parentOrder.getT2))
        .share()
    }
    
    Mono<Long> toppingMono = tupleToShare.flatMap....insertToppings....count()
    
    Mono<Long> conesMono = tupleToShare.flatMap......insertConeDetails.....count()
    
    Mono<Long> flavorsMono = tupleToShare.flatMap.....insertFlavorDetails......count()
    
    return Mono.zip(toppingMono,
                conesMono,
                flavorsMono)
                .then(Mono.just("Order process complete"))
                
    Flux<String> saveMasterOrder(Order order) {
        saveMasterOrderImpl.insertOrder(order)
        return ...
    }
    
}

// TEST
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.webEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfile("Test")
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class IceCreamOrderTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;
    @Autowired
    private DatabaseClient databaseClient;
    
    @BeforeAll
    public void setUp() {
        var jsonObj = new ClassPathResource("icecreamorder.json");
        webTestClient.post()
            .uri("/icecreamorder")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromResource(jsonObj))
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk();
    }
    
    // This test fails beause it finds 3 as the Mono.zip(with 3 Monos) above does not execute 
    // in paralell but sequentially. this causes the processOrder flux to run 3 times instead
    // just once. 
    @Test
    void testMasterOrderTable() {
        String sql = """
            select * 
            from master_order_table
            """;
        databaseClient.sql(sql)
            .fetch()
            .all()
            .as(StepVerifier::create)
            .expectNextCount(1)
            .verifyComplete();
    }
}
```

I want to mention again everything works when running the actual application, just not in testing. I know the code above is weird but its the best representation I could re-create without having to get into how complex the actual code is.

To make sure it was the Mono.zip, I added and took away parameters for this and the amount of entries I saw in the testing database was proportionate to how many parameters were in the Mono.zipo().

I have tried researching reasons why Flux would run sequentially. One resource mentioned that WebTestClient as 1 threadpool by default which might cause a limit in parallel processes. I tried to find ways to change the number of threadpools but I could not figure out how to correctly implement the configuration. Such configurations included changing the base Http client and WebClient.

I can also create an object and use the Service directly, but the object is quite large and complicated and would take a considerable amount of time to write a de-serializer for.